# Why equal comparison says false whereas typeof says they're share the same type and strings are the same?

Tags: javascript

Here is the thing, I want to generate 10 numbers formatted like in French phone numbers and then ask the user to spell each digit and for each digit I want to compare is answer with the right solution. And here is my problem, when I try to compare the answer with the solution, JavaScript always says false even if the answer is the correct answer. As you will see in the code I've tried to compare types and types are the same, even when I've tried to display the answer and the solution we can see on the screen that they are the same. 
If anyone has got an idea it would be great.

Here is my code:

```
function getRandomInt(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
};

var phone_nb1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var phone_nb2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

function convertArrayIntoRandom(array, max) {
    for (step = 0; step < array.length; step++)
    array[step] = getRandomInt(max);
    return array;
};

phone_nb1 = convertArrayIntoRandom(phone_nb1, 10);
phone_nb2 = convertArrayIntoRandom(phone_nb2, 10);


function convertDigitsIntoPhoneNb(array, sizeOfChunk) {
    var result = "";
    for (step = 0; step < array.length; step++) {
         result += array[step];
         if ( ( (step % sizeOfChunk) == 1 ) && (step < (array.length - 1) ) )
            result += '-';
    };
    return result;
};

function question(array) {
    document.write("<ol>");
    document.write("<li>");
    document.write("<p>How do you spell this phone number, digit by digit: " + array + " </p>");
    document.write("</li>");
    document.write("</ol>");
 };

question(convertDigitsIntoPhoneNb(phone_nb1, 2));

function numberToEnglish(n, custom_join_character) {

    var string = n.toString(),
    units, tens, scales, start, end, chunks,
    chunksLen, chunk, ints, i, word, words;

    var and = custom_join_character || 'and';

   /* Is number zero? */
   if (parseInt(string) === 0) {
       return 'zero';
   }

   /* Array of units as words */
   units = ['', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six',
     'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve',
     'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen',
     'eighteen', 'nineteen'];

   /* Array of tens as words */
   tens = ['', '', 'twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty',
     'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety'];

   /* Array of scales as words */
   scales = ['', 'thousand', 'million', 'billion', 'trillion',
      'quadrillion', 'quintillion', 'sextillion',
      'septillion', 'octillion', 'nonillion', 'decillion',
      'undecillion', 'duodecillion', 'tredecillion',
      'quatttuor-decillion', 'quindecillion',
      'sexdecillion', 'septen-decillion', 'octodecillion',
      'novemdecillion', 'vigintillion', 'centillion'];

    /* Split user argument into 3 digit chunks from right to 
       left */
    start = string.length;
    chunks = [];
    while (start > 0) {
        end = start;
        chunks.push(string.slice((start = Math.max(0, start - 3)), end));
    }

    /* Check if function has enough scale words to be able to 
       stringify the user argument */
    chunksLen = chunks.length;
    if (chunksLen > scales.length) {
    return '';
    }

    /* Stringify each integer in each chunk */
    words = [];
    for (i = 0; i < chunksLen; i++) {

    chunk = parseInt(chunks[i]);

    if (chunk) {

        /* Split chunk into array of individual integers */
        ints = chunks[i].split('').reverse().map(parseFloat);

        /* If tens integer is 1, i.e. 10, then add 10 to 
           units integer */
        if (ints[1] === 1) {
             ints[0] += 10;
        }

        /* Add scale word if chunk is not zero and array item 
           exists */
        if ((word = scales[i])) {
            words.push(word);
        }

        /* Add unit word if array item exists */
        if ((word = units[ints[0]])) {
            words.push(word);
        }

        /* Add tens word if array item exists */
        if ((word = tens[ints[1]])) {
            words.push(word);
        }

        /* Add 'and' string after units or tens integer if: */
        if (ints[0] || ints[1]) {

            /* Chunk has a hundreds integer or chunk is the 
               first of multiple chunks */
            if (ints[2] || !i && chunksLen) {
                words.push(and);
            }
        }

        /* Add hundreds word if array item exists */
        if ((word = units[ints[2]])) {
            words.push(word + ' hundred');
        }

      }
   }

   return words.reverse().join(' ');

};

numberToEnglish(1);

var active_or_not = prompt("Do you want to answer to this question right now? Yes or no? ");


function convertDigitArrayToWordsArray(digitArray) {
    var wordsArray = [];
    for (step = 0; step < digitArray.length; step++)
    wordsArray += ' ' + numberToEnglish(digitArray[step], ' ');
    return wordsArray;
};


if (active_or_not.toUpperCase() == "YES") {

    var solution1 = convertDigitArrayToWordsArray(phone_nb1);

    var credit = 0;

    for (step = 0; step < 10; step++) {
         var temp = prompt("How to spell " + phone_nb1[step] + ": ");
         var testLeft = temp.toUpperCase();
         document.write("<p>Type of testLeft = " + typeof testLeft + "</p>");
         var testRight = numberToEnglish(phone_nb1[step], ' ').toUpperCase();
         document.write("<p>Type of testRight = " + typeof testRight + "</p>");
         alert(testLeft === testRight);
         alert(testLeft == testRight);
         if (testLeft === testRight) {
             credit++;
             alert("You've done good job! Keep going!");
         } else {
               alert("That's not the right answer. Keep going and when you finish go check the solution.");
               document.write("<p style='color: red; font-size: 1.25em;'>Your answer is " + testLeft + "</p>");
               document.write("<p style='color: green; font-size: 1.5em;'>The right answer is " + testRight + "</p>");
        };
    };

    document.write("<p style='color: green;'>The complete solution is: " + solution1.toUpperCase() + "</p>");
```

I use the numberToEnglish function that I've found here (https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/353/how-to-convert-numbers-to-words-number-spelling-in-javascript).

By the way, you can also find the complete code of my project on GitHub here https://github.com/lgsp/sciencelanguages/tree/master/html/english

Thanks by advance for anyone who can help me.

Comment: Before posting, please reduce the code to the **minimum** required to replicate the problem, don't post a wall of code for everyone to wade through. (Not least because the process of doing that usually helps you find your solution.) More: [mcve]. Ideally, make that MCVE *runnable* using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: Sorry, inexplicably forgot to say: Welcome to Stack Overflow! *(That's what I get for starting out with the wrong canned reply and not editing thoroughly enough.)*

Comment: You're missing to declare the `step` loop counters as `var`. (Should not cause a problem here, but might in general)